# Example of Simple phone webapp, requesting and consuming from Django Server, JSON objects via RESTful API

Tags: django, rest, web-applications

I am looking for a basic example, a little more than a "hello world" example which probably has:

1) user1 using his webapp on his phone, logging in with an username/password
2) requesting list of books he has read, which is kept on the server

Server sending User1 with the list of books that User1 has read on the site

Similarly, if User2 asks the same request to server, the book list sent via JSON would be for User2

Any example of this kind that helps me understand how models stored at the Django server end is sent as JSON objects, and then is consumed by the webapp and shown on phone-screen

Thanks

Comment: You have to show us what you have tried. We would be glad to help you figure it out but we can't architect the full stack for you.

Comment: This is part of it http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers

Comment: I have tried this front-end Sencha app : http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/oreilly/

This works well on the front-end, but as you will observe, the Tweets feeds are all from an JSON Ipsum generator. I want to understand how I can write a django app on server that can provide these JSON feeds.